# Call a function from another ViewModel

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, navigation

I´m a beginner in this language, trying to learn more about the best practices and hows to do the things better...

I have this repo as example application: https://github.com/Albvadi/NavigationMVVM

If you run it, all works well. You can navigate to others views and increment a counter shared in all views.

But, If you uncomment the `ActualView` assignation in `MainViewModel.cs` file at line 24 and put a login view in front of the `InitialView` I don´t know how to redirect the user to the `Initialview` after login success.

When the login is correct, I fill the user data in the ManagerData and with all of this I need to call the function in the `MainViewModel` to redirect the user to the Initial view. How can I make that call from the `LoginViewModel` to the other `MainViewModel` instead from the View?

UPDATE: Add the code relevant

`App.xaml`

```xml
<Application
    x:Class="NavigationMVVM.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:NavigationMVVM"
    xmlns:Views="clr-namespace:NavigationMVVM.Views"
    xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:NavigationMVVM.ViewModels"
    StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    
    <Application.Resources>
        <DataTemplate
            DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:MainViewModel}">
            <local:MainWindow />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate
            DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:LoginViewModel}">
            <Views:Login />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate
            DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:InitialViewModel}">
            <Views:Initial />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate
            DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:FirstViewModel}">
            <Views:First />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate
            DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:SecondViewModel}">
            <Views:Second />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

`MainWindow.xaml`

```xml
<Window
    x:Class="NavigationMVVM.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:NavigationMVVM"
    xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:NavigationMVVM.ViewModels"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Height="450"
    Width="800">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <viewModels:MainViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Grid>
        <ContentControl
            Content="{Binding ActualView}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

`BaseViewModel.cs`

```cs
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace NavigationMVVM.Common
{
    public class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private BaseViewModel _ActualView;
        public BaseViewModel ActualView
        {
            get => _ActualView;
            set
            {
                _ActualView = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(null);
            }
        }

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void RaisePropertyChanged(string PropertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

`MainViewModel.cs`

```cs
using NavigationMVVM.Common;
using NavigationMVVM.Models;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace NavigationMVVM.ViewModels
{
    public class MainViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        public DataManager SharedData = new DataManager();

        public InitialViewModel InitialVM;
        public FirstViewModel FirstVM;
        public SecondViewModel SecondVM;
        public LoginViewModel LoginVM;

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            LoginVM = new LoginViewModel(SharedData);
            InitialVM = new InitialViewModel(SharedData);
            FirstVM = new FirstViewModel(SharedData);
            SecondVM = new SecondViewModel(SharedData);

            ActualView = InitialVM;
            //ActualView = LoginVM;
        }

        public ICommand DisplayFirstView
        {
            get
            {
                return new RelayCommand(action => ActualView = FirstVM,
              canExecute => true);
            }
        }

        public ICommand DisplaySecondView
        {
            get
            {
                return new RelayCommand(action => ActualView = SecondVM,
              canExecute => true);
            }
        }

        public ICommand DisplayInitialView
        {
            get
            {
                return new RelayCommand(action => ActualView = InitialVM,
              canExecute => true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`LoginViewModel.cs`

```cs
using NavigationMVVM.Common;
using NavigationMVVM.Models;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace NavigationMVVM.ViewModels
{
    public class LoginViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        private DataManager _DataManager;

        public ICommand LoginCmd;
        public RelayCommand DoLoginCmd { get; }


        private string _Username;
        public string Username
        {
            get => _Username;
            set
            {
                _Username = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(null);
            }
        }

        private string _Password;
        public string Password
        {
            get => _Password;
            set
            {
                _Password = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(null);
            }
        }

        private string _MessageInfo;
        public string MessageInfo
        {
            get => _MessageInfo;
            set
            {
                _MessageInfo = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(null);
            }
        }

        public LoginViewModel(DataManager sharedData)
        {
            _DataManager = sharedData;
            DoLoginCmd = new RelayCommand(param => DoLogin(), canExec => (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Username) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Password)));
        }

        public void DoLogin()
        {
            if (Username == "admin" && Password == "password")
            {
                _DataManager.User.Name = "Administrator";
                _DataManager.User.Mail = "admin@company.com";

                MessageInfo = "Login OK!... How to redirect??";
            }
            else
            {
                MessageInfo = "Username or Password incorrect!";
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please include relevant piece of code into the question. [Meta topic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/80978/299295).

Comment: Please remember that Stackoverflow is not only for your benefit. It's for others that run into similar problems as well. Once you fix your problem on your github project this question stops making sense. Therefore: Post the relevant code here.

Comment: You're right, I thought it would be easier to see the complete code than to ask a very long question with too much code. Can you reopen the question or do I delete it and create a new one? Thanks a lot.

Comment: You are holding all the VMs so you could just use simple events that the MainViewModel will register to from each of the child VMs and handle accordingly. But if you want true separation, maybe later you will remove the child VMs, you can use Publisher\Subscriber pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to accomplish what you want. I'll post two approaches that are very common when working in an MVVM pattern
Event based approach:

```
 public MainViewModel()
        {
            LoginVM = new LoginViewModel(SharedData);
            LoginVM.PropertyChanged += LoginVM_PropertyChanged;
            InitialVM = new InitialViewModel(SharedData);
            FirstVM = new FirstViewModel(SharedData);
            SecondVM = new SecondViewModel(SharedData);

            //ActualView = InitialVM;
            ActualView = LoginVM;
        }

        private void LoginVM_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
           if(sender.GetType() == typeof(LoginViewModel) && e.PropertyName == "MessageInfo")
            {
                var loginVM = (LoginViewModel)sender;
                if (loginVM.MessageInfo == "OK")
                {
                    ActualView = InitialVM;
                }
            }
        }
```

Cunstructor Injection:

```
        private Action _loginAction;
        public LoginViewModel(DataManager sharedData, Action loginAction )
        {
            _DataManager = sharedData;
            DoLoginCmd = new RelayCommand(param => DoLogin(), canExec => (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Username) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Password)));
            _loginAction = loginAction;
        }

        public void DoLogin()
        {
            if (Username == "admin" && Password == "password")
            {
                _DataManager.User.Name = "Administrator";
                _DataManager.User.Mail = "admin@company.com";
             
                MessageInfo = "Login OK!... How to redirect??";
                _loginAction.Invoke();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageInfo = "Username or Password incorrect!";
            }

        }
```

and

```
 public MainViewModel()
        {
            LoginVM = new LoginViewModel(SharedData, () => ActualView = InitialVM);            
            InitialVM = new InitialViewModel(SharedData);
            FirstVM = new FirstViewModel(SharedData);
            SecondVM = new SecondViewModel(SharedData);
            //ActualView = InitialVM;
            ActualView = LoginVM;
        }
```

Side note: to put a property "ActualView" on the BaseViewModel is a rather odd choice

Comment: I have been studying how to use Publisher \ Subscriber, but I have not succeeded yet. I will test your options as soon as possible and if I do, I will mark it as a valid answer. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Tested and worked perfectly!. I put the property in the BaseViewModel to share and access in all the viewmodels, but after this I have seen that it does not make sense. I'll remove it from there. Thanks so much!